# Use of createAlias in grails / Hibernate criteria

Tags: hibernate, grails, hibernate-criteria

In grails there is very less documentation (as much as I could find) about the createAlias().

```
PurchasedSessionHistory.withCriteria {
        createAlias("customer", "_customer", JoinType.LEFT_OUTER_JOIN)
        createAlias("_customer.user", "_user", JoinType.LEFT_OUTER_JOIN)
        createAlias("membership", "_membership", JoinType.LEFT_OUTER_JOIN)
        createAlias("promotion", "_promotion", JoinType.LEFT_OUTER_JOIN)


// .....

}
```

In above code(from an already existing codebase), why do we need to define an alias on the "customer" property (of the `Customer` class that is nested in `PurchasedSessionHistory`).

Why can't I access the "user" property directly on the "customer" and have to define an alias?

In general what is the use of createAlias in such cases?

Comment: Guessing it has something to do with the fact that "session" is a reserved word in most databases, but I can't be positive.

Comment: @ToddSharp i changed the example. It doesn't have to do anything with that word because this is also the case when we use any other domain instance.

Comment: This used to be possible in Grails 2.3/ maybe 2.5 , but certainly not 3.  I know as I have a situation now where my old code isn't working that specified Joins for an association I refer to in a projection.   Hibernate doesn't like me specifying the association name and join type as a parameter (any longer!) - so as a workaround, I am creating an alias for the association and referencing the association field through that e.g. projections { property 'myalias.city' }

Comment: @Dave I am on grails 2.4.5